# Como editar o gráfico de barras a seguir no R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de entender como posso fazer as seguintes alterações no gráfico a seguir:

- Alterar a escala do eixo Y e ocultá-la do gráfico caso queira
- Colocar os valores em cima de cada barra
- Colocar os meses do eixo X na ordem crescente (junho... julho..) e colocar em negrito a escrita

Estou utilizando o seguinte script:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

TCH <- data.frame(Período =c("Jun", "Jul"), 
                         CV6654 = c(9.38, 26.14), CTC9002 = c(16.27, 47.71))

df <- gather(TCH, "Variedades", "Valor", -Período)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Período), y = Valor, fill = Variedades)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("1", "3")) +
  labs(x = "Período", y = "")
```

[image: gráfico gerado com o script acima]

Comment: 1) Alterar para quê? 2) veja `geom_text` ou `geom_label`; 3) `x = factor(Período, levels = c("Jun", "Jul"))`.

Comment: Olá Patrick, bem vindo ao SOpt. Algumas dicas para ter sua pergunta respondida satisfatoriamente: 1) Seja específico quanto ao resultado que busca. Quer alterar a escala do eixo como? Para escala logarítmica? Fração? Porcentagem? Sem especificar, conseguirá no máximo uma resposta genérica. 2) Divida suas dúvidas em várias postagens. Idealmente, cada questão deve se referir a um único problema. Isso auxilia outros usuários quando buscarem solução e auxilia você a delimitar as etapas do seu código. Inclusive, se buscar pelas etapas separadas, encontrará no site respostas que talvez te ajudem.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Período), y = Valor, fill = Variedades)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("1", "3")) +
  geom_text(aes(y = Valor, label = Valor), vjust = -0.2, # COLOCAR VALORES EM CIMA DAS BARRAS
            position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Período", y = "") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), # APAGAR EIXO Y
        axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold")) + # ROTULO EIXO X EM NEGRITO 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("6", "7"),
                   labels=c("Junho", "Julho")) # REORDENANDO COLUNAS
```